# Export to Excel erroring when connected to VPN

Tags: sharepoint-online, spo, export-to-excel, vpn

In SPO, when I use the "Export to excel" functionality when connected to VPN, I receive the below error.

"The server you are trying to access is using an authentication protocol not supported by this version of Office"

When connected to Company network, "Export to Excel" is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the below steps to troubleshot this:

**Troubleshooting Approach 1**

**Step 1: Run CSISYNCCLIENT.EXE**

Using file explorer, open the CSISYNCCLIENT.EXE file found at the following address.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16

Right click and select 'Run as Administrator'.

**Step 2: Verify**

Verify the CSISYNCCLIENT.EXE is running by opening task manager and looking for 'CSISYNCCLIENT.EXE' in the process list. If it is not running try once again to 'Run as Administrator'.

**Step 3: Restart PC**

Once the process is verified as running, restart the PC.

Reference Articles:

[How to: The server you are trying to access is using an authentication protocol not supported by this version of Office](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/131463-the-server-you-are-trying-to-access-is-using-an-authentication-protocol-not-supported-by-this-version-of-office)

[[FIX] The Server You Are Trying To Access Is Using An Authentication Protocol Not Supported By This Version Of Office](https://www.kapilarya.com/the-server-you-are-trying-to-access-is-using-an-authentication-protocol-not-supported-by-this-version-of-office)

**Troubleshooting Approach 2**

You may try these troubleshooting steps regarding the error you encountered:

1. Clear Windows Credential:

   - On the Control Panel, go to User Accounts > Credential Manager >
     Manage Windows Credentials.
   - Delete all MicrosoftOffice15/MicrosoftOffice16 credentials.
2. Open Word/Excel application then go to File > Accounts. Sign out the current account and then login the Office 365 account with a valid OneDrive for Business license.

   3. Clear OneDrive for Business cache using Easy Fix Tool:

More on this troubleshooting in the below thread:

[The server you are trying to access is using an authentication protocol not supported by this version of Office](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/the-server-you-are-trying-to-access-is-using-an/6b2ba16e-8419-41d0-a4f1-974cb194093c?auth=1)

Note:

- By default if we are in VPN connection, we cannot connect to SharePoint online, first we need to disconnect from VPN, then login in SharePoint online, then again re-connect the VPN back, then this will continue to work as expected. This is the default behavior of VPN with respect to SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Office are you using? It seems that the "Export to excel" feature is in well function except when there is a network fluctuation.

Another thing you can try:

1. Open all Office applications except Excel and sign out of all other Office 365 accounts.
2. Remove all "Connected Services" listed under Office application > File > Account that don’t use current Office 365 account.
3. Close all applications and then try to export the list to Excel again.

Here’s another post with similar issue for your reference.

[Getting error “The server you are trying to access is using an authentication protocol not supported by this version of Office” in SharePoint online.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/gettting-error-the-server-you-are-trying-to-access/f5ccafe1-84be-4836-a663-70988b65af44)